# Editing Google Docs Files Through Batch File

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, ftp, edit

Is it possible to edit a text file (*.txt) that's public for editing in google Docs through Cmd or a batch file. Or Can I use the FTP Command? It can even be done by uploading and downloading the same file (Download, Edit, Upload).

I have made the Document That I want to add text to and re-upload it per say. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qbLnCcNlcMQ1VSQkFoSmJxc1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you have google Drive installed on your machine, just make a `copy` in the right Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the ftp side goes, afaik google docs don't support ftp access
But a 3rd party program called Cyberduck comes handy at [this point](http://tjhouston.com/2011/08/access-backup-your-google-docs-via-ftp/)

So passing some arguments to cyberduck might do the trick

But if you also want to access a 3rd party ftp server
than it is also possible using the [ftp command](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/)